# Раскрасить железную дорогу так, чтобы любые две соседние станции были покрашены в разные цвета

Tags: pascal

Прошу помочь разобраться с олимпиадной задачей (она уже прошла, так что это просто для тренировки). Ну вот, я написал код на паскале (опыт в нем не очень большой, но лучше, чем ничего). Программа работает, но превышает лимит по времени на одном из тестов. Вот теперь не знаю как ее оптимизировать. Решение можете писать на любом языке, если захотите.

[Вот сама задача](http://codeforces.com/gym/101627/problem/C)

**Задача A. Railroad**

Имя входного файла: стандартный ввод
Имя выходного файла: стандартный вывод
Ограничение по времени: 2 секунды
Ограничение по памяти: 512 мегабайт

Ане на День Рождения подарили огромную игрушечную железную дорогу. Железная дорога
состоит из станций и перегонов. Каждый железнодорожный перегон соединяет две станции. Две
станции назовем соседними, если они соединены перегоном.
По каким-то странным причинам некоторые станции в наборе были изначально покрашены в
некоторые цвета, а некоторые — оставлены непокрашенными. При этом у каждой непокрашенной
станции не более двух соседних непокрашенных станций. Аня решила покрасить все непокрашенные станции. Для этого у нее есть краски k различных цветов. Она любит пестрые раскраски,
поэтому хочет, чтобы в финальной раскраске железной дороги любые две соседние станции были
покрашены в разные цвета.

Помогите Ане покрасить станции так, чтобы это условие выполнялось, или скажите, что сделать
это невозможно. Помните, что Аня хочет покрасить только непокрашенные станции, перекрашивать
уже покрашенные станции она не будет.

**Формат входных данных**
В первой строке содержатся три целых числа n, m и k — количество станций, перегонов и цветов,
соответственно (1 ⩽ n ⩽ 2 · 105
; 0 ⩽ m ⩽ 4 · 105
; 1 ⩽ k ⩽ n).

В следующей строке содержатся n чисел, описывающих цвета станций. Цвета занумерованы
числами от 1 до k, если станция не покрашена, то соответствующее число равно −1.
В последующих m строках содержится описание перегонов. Каждая строка состоит из двух
целых чисел vi и ui — номеров станций, соединенных i-м перегоном (1 ⩽ vi
, ui ⩽ n, vi ̸= ui).
Гарантируется, что у каждой непокрашенной станции не более двух соседних непокрашенных
станций, и что любые две соседние покрашенные станции имеют разные цвета.

**Формат выходных данных**
В первой строке выведите «Yes», если требуемая раскраска существует, или «No», в противном
случае.

Если раскраска существует, то в следующей строке выведите n целых чисел, описывающих цвета,
в которые требуется раскрасить станции. Обратите внимание, что перекрашивать уже покрашенные
станции нельзя. Если существует несколько решений, выведите любое.

А вот код:

```
  program Task2;

  label start, _end;

  var
    n, m, k, i, j: integer;
    c: array of integer;
    d: array of array[0..1] of integer;
    o: array of List<integer>;

  begin
    readln(n, m, k);
    SetLength(c, n);
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
      read(c[i]);
    SetLength(d, m);
    for i := 0 to m - 1 do
    begin
      readln(d[i][0], d[i][1]);
    end;

    SetLength(o, n);

    start:
    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      o[i] := new List<integer>();
      if c[i] = -1 then
      begin
        o[i].AddRange(Range(1, k));
        for j := 0 to m - 1 do
        begin
          if d[j][0] = i + 1 then
            o[i].Remove(c[d[j][1] - 1])
          else if d[j][1] = i + 1 then
            o[i].Remove(c[d[j][0] - 1]);
        end;
        if o[i].Count = 1 then
          c[i] := o[i].Item[0];
      end
      else
        o[i].Add(-1);
    end;

    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
      if o[i].Count = 0 then
      begin
        writeln('No');
        goto _end;
        break;
      end;

    for i := 0 to n - 1 do
      if (o[i].Count > 0) and (o[i].Item[0] <> -1) then
      begin
        c[i] := o[i].Item[0];
        goto start;
        break;
      end;

    writeln('Yes');
    writeln(c.JoinIntoString());
    _end:
  end.
```

***Не кидайтесь сильно тапками за этот код)***

Comment: обычно в олимпиадной задаче если решение не прошло по таймлимиту, значит что вы не тот алгоритм используете :)

Comment: @teran, это логично) Вот я и хочу узнать, какой алгоритм нужно использовать.

Comment: надеюсь вы же знаете что это задача о раскраске графа с некоторым ограничениями (в виде уже раскрашенных некоторых вершин)? это в принципе классическая задача из комбинаторики и теории графов, вы знакомы с соответствующими алгоритмами? или писали что-то свое?

Comment: @teran, теорию графов не проходил, комбинаторику знаю только немногим больше школьной программы. Простите, конечно, если задача простая, а я сильно глуплю) В любом случае спасибо за наводку, теперь знаю свои слабые места

Comment: а я хз простая она или нет :) просто подкидываю мысль, что надо искать алгоритмы решения задачи раскраски графа :) я это изучал весьма давно и графы не были моей любимой темой почему-то :)